# I'm Saudi, have got my Schengen visa and I'd like to visit Bora Bora "French Polynesia"?

Tags: visas, schengen, french-polynesia, saudi-citizens

I am Saudi and got my Schengen visa and i'd like to visit Bora Bora "French Polynesia" for a week or less.

Do I need a certain visa to go there or would the Schengen visa be ok?

(Note: I applied for the Schengen from the Swiss Embassy.)

Answer (score 10):

You are not able to use your Schengen Visa to enter Bora Bora. Instead you should apply for  "**visa for French Overseas collectivities**". You must apply this visa directly to French Embassy.

For detail, please take a look at this [article](http://www.ambafrance-sg.org/Visa-for-French-overseas) from French Embassy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/580/rudy.

Comment: No problem. If this answer works for you, don't forget to change it to accepted answer.